# Splitting a list into parts then shuffling those parts: Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

The question is: Define a function `shuffle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` that takes a
natural number n and an even-lengthed list, and splits and then riffles the list n times. For example, `shuffle 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6] = [1,5,4,3,2,6]`. I have a function riffle that works accordingly, but I don't know how to split a list.

My riffle function is:

```
riffle :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
riffle [] ys = ys
riffle xs [] = xs
riffle (x:xs)(y:ys) = x : y : riffle xs ys
```

I started shuffle, I think, here is what I have:

```
shuffle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle [] = []
shuffle a xs = (length xs) 'div' a
```

I was attempting to take a list and divide into parts specified "a". I'm new to Haskell and am still not certain how it all works: All help is appreciated.

Comment: Say I call `shuffle 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and tomorrow I call it again with the same input. Do you want/expect the outcome to be the same? Because that is what func prog / Haskell  is all about (and more of course).

Comment: @Elmex80s I would expect the output to be the same, yes.

Comment: Splitting a list: `Data.List.splitAt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To split a list in half, with both halves in order, you should generally use a tortoise and hare algorithm.

```
-- split2 xs = splitAt (length xs `quot` 2) xs
split2 :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split2 xs0 = go xs0 xs0
  where
    go (_:_:hs) (t:ts) =
      let (front, rear) = go hs ts
      in (t:front, rear)
    go _ ts = ([], ts)
```

This should generally be more efficient than calculating the length of the list and dividing by two. It will also work even if the list is infinite.

---

In this case, however, you don't need a lazy version; you're going to use the second half pretty much immediately. So you can use this more Lisp/Scheme/ML-style version if you prefer:

```
split2' :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split2' xs0 = go [] xs0 xs0
  where
    go front (_:_:hs) (t:ts) = go (t:front) hs ts
    go front _ ts = (reverse front, ts)
```

I'm not sure which will be faster, but `split2'` is less susceptible to space leaks introduced by compiler transformations.

Answer (score 1):

not a good shuffle, your first and last elements never move.

something like this?

```
> let shuffle 0 x = x
      shuffle n x = shuffle (n-1) $ uncurry riffle $ splitAt (length x `div` 2) x
```

or with iterate